# Is ON DUPLICATE KEY functionality possible when doing an UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql

I'm familiar with using the ON DUPLICATE KEY construct when doing INSERT queries.  I'd like to do the same with an UPDATE query, but it seems to be not allowed in MySQL, or else I just don't know the syntax.

My table has a unique index, and I want my UPDATE query to update as many records as it can, and ignore or delete records that would cause a duplicate key.  The hypothetical query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE votes SET user = 'foo' WHERE user = 'bar'
  ON DUPLICATE KEY <ignore update or delete row>;
```

I'm trying to merge 2 users in my database.  Where that user already has an existing vote on a topic, the duplicate vote can be ignored, but I don't want the whole query to fail when this happens.  Ideally I'd like to delete any records that trigger the duplicate key, and if that can be rolled into the query, so much the better.

This would be a fairly rare event, so if this functionality just plain doesn't exist with UPDATE, I'm open to answers that accomplish what I want with multiple queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "update as many records as it can"? The query only updates one record.

Comment: No, there may be 1000 votes for a given user.  If updates to 10 of those 1000 would cause a dupe key, I want the 990 to succeed and the 10 to be ignored or deleted.

Comment: I probably didn't include enough info about my Votes table.  The unique key is on user + topic.  A user may have any number of votes on various topics, but can't have multiple votes on the same topic.  When merging users, we run into the case where those (previously separate) users voted on the same topic.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should edit the question to show how the topic fits into this, rather than just having it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for this with a self-join:

```
UPDATE votes AS v1
LEFT JOIN votes AS v2 ON v1.topic = v2.topic AND v2.user = 'foo'
SET v1.user = 'foo'
WHERE v1.user = 'bar'
AND v2.user IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd9a/1)

It's not possible to combine `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in a single query. You need to do them separately, using a transaction to ensure atomicity. The `DELETE` query should only delete the records that would be duplicated based on the topic.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE v1 FROM votes AS v1
JOIN votes AS v2 ON v1.topic = v2.topic
WHERE v1.user = 'foo' AND v2.user = 'bar';
UPDATE votes SET user = 'foo' WHERE user = 'bar';
COMMIT;
```